# What is the algorithm that dropbox uses to identify list of files/folders changed locally when the app was not running?

Tags: algorithm, dropbox, synchronization

I understand that we can identify the changes in File System when the app is running using some OS events. I am just wondering when the app is not running, If I make lots of changes on the file system like add / modify / delete / rename few files and folders, What algorithm does Dropbox uses to identify these changes. One thing I could think of is, by comparing last modified time of a file on the file system against LMT stored value when the app was running. In this case, we had to loop through all the files anyways. However, LMT doesn't change if we do rename. Just wanted to see is there any better approach as relying on LMT has its own problems?

Any comments?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's how Dropbox handles it but here is a strategy that may be useful:

You have a root directory handled by Dropbox. If I were Dropbox, I'ld keep hashes for each file I have on the server. Starting from the root, the app would scan the file tree (directories + files) and compute the hashes for each file.

The scan would lead to a double index hashtable. Each file and directory would be indexed using its relative path (from the root Dropbox directory). A second index would be made using the hash(es) of each file.

Now, the app has scanned and established the double-indexed hashtable. The server would then send the tuples (*relative path*, *hashes of the file*). Let (*f*, *h*) be such a file tuple:

1. The app would try to get the file through the path index using *f*:

   1. If there is a result, compare the hashes. If they don't match, update the file on the remote server
   2. If there is no result the file may have been deleted OR moved/renamed. The app then tries to get the file through the hash index using *h*: if there is a match, that means the file is still there only under a different path (hence moved or renamed). The app send the info and the file is appropriately moved/renamed on the server.
2. The file has not been found neither using the hash or the path. It has been deleted from the Dropbox file tree: we delete it accordingly on the server.

Note that this strategy needs a synchronization mechanism to know, when meeting a match, if the file has to be updated on the client or on the server. This could be achieved by storing the time of the last update run by Dropbox (on the client and the server) and who performed this last update (on the server).

Comment: Thanks Rerito. Can you little elaborate on second index which is hash of a file. What is the hash represents here? I think its better to take an example. Lets say I have synced hierarchy in both cloud & local like this. /file1.txt, /file2.txt, /folder1/file3.txt. Now lets assume I quit the app and now i made changes in the local file system a) removed file1.txt b) added new folder2 like /folder2/file4.txt and I made changes in cloud a)Removed file2.txt b) Renamed folder1 to folder4 c) Added folder5. How does this approach works and finds the local & cloud changes once when the app started?